# How to save hyperLogLog field to BigQuery from ApacheBeam with Data Flow runner

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, hyperloglog

I need to save HLL sketches into BigQuery from ApacheBeam.

I found some extension [library](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/extensions/sketching) for Apache-Beam that does it:

But I can't find a way to save the sketch itself to BigQuery. to be able to use it later with merge function and other functions  by some time sliding: see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hll_functions)

my code:

```
 .apply("hll-count",  Combine.perKey(ApproximateDistinct.ApproximateDistinctFn
                            .create(StringUtf8Coder.of())))
.apply("reify-windows", Reify.windows())
                    .apply("to-table-row", ParDo.of(new DoFn< ValueInSingleWindow<KV<GroupByData,HyperLogLogPlus>>, TableRow>() {
                        @ProcessElement
                        public void processElement(ProcessContext processContext) {
                            ValueInSingleWindow<KV<GroupByData,HyperLogLogPlus>> windowed = processContext.element();
                            KV<GroupByData, HyperLogLogPlus> keyData = windowed.getValue();
                            GroupByData key = keyData.getKey();

                            HyperLogLogPlus hyperLogLogPlus = keyData.getValue();
                            if (key != null) {

                                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
                                tableRow.set("country_code",key.countryCode);
                                tableRow.set("event", key.event);
                                tableRow.set("profile", key.profile);

                                 tableRow.set("occurrences", hyperLogLogPlus.cardinality());
```

I just found how to do `hyperLogLogPlus.cardinality()` but how can write the buffer itself, in way I can run on it later merge function, in BiGQuery.

Using `hyperLogLogPlus.getBytes` also didn't work for merge.

Comment: Seems like  Apache Beam are working on it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123269269#comment5 and here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2728?focusedCommentId=16810050&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16810050

Comment: Update: A BigQuery-compatible implementation of HyperLogLog++ has been open-sourced to https://github.com/google/zetasketch, and a design doc (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U5aXdC9lDSOqT6FPHRulp-EutYiQ9KeHpgu-19CIfEI) about integrating it into Apache Beam has been sent out to dev@beam.apache.org.

Answer (score 2):

Currently this functionality is not supported by Apache Beam, but there are people working on it.

To be specific:
The [extension library](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/extensions/sketching) in Apache Beam you mentioned depends on [this](https://github.com/addthis/stream-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/clearspring/analytics/stream/cardinality/HyperLogLogPlus.java) HyperLogLog implementation. The sketches produced by this library is not consistent with the [sketches](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hll_functions) computed by Google Cloud BigQuery. So it wouldn't make sense to merge sketches in BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was first asked in 2019 April, a BigQuery-compatible implementation of HLL sketch has been released, as noted in this GCP blog post, [Using HLL++ to speed up count-distinct in massive datasets](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/using-hll-speed-count-distinct-massive-datasets).

The post has illustrative code snippets showing how to save the HLL sketches to BigQuery as well as to GCS files.

Quoting the relevant parts of the post:

> [The Google implementation of HyperLogLog] was added to BigQuery in 2017 and has recently been open sourced and made directly available in Apache Beam as of version 2.16. That means it’s available for use in Cloud Dataflow ...
>
> Note: As of version 2.16, there are several implementations of approximate count algorithms. We recommend the use of [HllCount.java](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/zetasketch/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/zetasketch/HllCount.java), especially if you need sketches and/or need compatibility with Google Cloud BigQuery.

From section 3 of the post, "Storing the sketches in BigQuery":

> BigQuery supports HLL++ via the HLL_COUNT functions, and BigQuery’s sketches are fully compatible with Beam’s, so it’s easy to interoperate with sketch objects across both systems.
>
> In the example below we will:
>   1. Pre-aggregate data into sketches in Beam;
>   2. Store the sketches in BigQuery as byte[] columns along with some metadata about the time interval;
>   3. Run a rollup query in BigQuery, which can extract the results at interactive speed, thanks to the sketches that were pre-computed in Beam.

Comment: i can't see how to use it in beam sql.. (only by copy the code and create my own transformer)